# Select Query on Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The question may be very simple  but i don't know how to fix it,

I have this table structure

```
sno  left Right
1    2      1
2    2      2
3    1      2
4    3      1 
5    2      4
6    7      1    
7    2      8
```

How do I get a result set like the one below

```
sno  left   Right Result
1    2      1     1
2    2      2     2
3    1      2     1
4    3      1     1
5    2      4     2
6    7      1     1
7    2      8     2
```

I wanna select the Data what mimimum value is matched between two columns,

Eg:`3  and 1`

1 is minimum value between these two and 1 is matched with 3, so the matched value is 1.

eg: `2 and 4`

2 is minimum value between these two and 2 is is mathed with 4, so the matched value is 2.

Edited:

If choose 8 and 2 for example

8 contains(**1,2**,3,4,5,6,7,8)

2 contains(**1,2**)

So the Result is **2**

Because 2 values are matched here.
I hope i explained it well, thanks

Comment: nope, Im not calculating the diff between those  two columns @jarlh

Comment: That's what @jarlh is doing, calculating the difference: left - right

Comment: So, are you saying that if left is smaller then 1, if right is smaller then 2, if both are equal then 0?

Comment: Im not calculating the Difference .

Comment: Ok, now we know what you're **not** calculating. Could you please explain **what** you're calculating?

Comment: I have updated my Result set again. Please check it, @splattne

Comment: You should update your example data also, currently it's quite confusing, 5 rows input, 8 rows output,

Comment: Updated .@dnoeth, Thanks for your patience guys

Comment: 2      2     0 whay for 2 2 result is 0?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri  sorry, its a typo

Comment: @King_Fisher, this is just a minimum. Why are you overcomplicationg this?

Comment: Yea, i was mentioned that on my first example.

Comment: Minimum Value of a row @GiorgiNakeuri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( sno INT, l INT, r INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 2, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2, 2 ),
        ( 3, 1, 2 ),
        ( 4, 3, 1 ),
        ( 5, 2, 4 ),
        ( 6, 7, 1 ),
        ( 7, 2, 8 )


SELECT *,
    (SELECT MIN(v) FROM (VALUES(l),(r)) m(v)) AS m
FROM @t
```

Output:

```
sno l   r   m
1   2   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   1   2   1
4   3   1   1
5   2   4   2
6   7   1   1
7   2   8   2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but  i didn't get your query, you have used 'v' but you didn't declared that, what kind of query is this.

Comment: `(VALUES(l),(r))` this is table expression with 1 column and 2 rows l and r then you call it m(v) i.e. table name is m and column name is v.

Comment: Can you refer me any article related  your query

Comment: @King_Fisher, http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10905/interesting-enhancements-to-the-values-clause-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The following SQL will return the positive value of a subtraction operation between the left and right values - in a column with Result as the header. It will calculate the difference between left and right values - ABS will make the result positive.

```
SELECT
    sno,
    left,
    Right,
    ABS(left - right) AS Result
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Im NOT Calculating the Difference .:)

Comment: I have updated  my Result set again. Please check it,

Answer (score 1):

```
case 
     when left < right then left 
     else right 
end
```

Comment: Sir, I have Update with example .

Comment: @King_Fisher: Your example simply returns the lower of both values, which is exactly what this CASE is doing.

Comment: Based on your modified examples it's even simpler... Btw, most DBMSes support a function like `LEAST` for this kind of logic.

Comment: But,whats the condition if both values are same?

Comment: Im using Sql server 2008 , It doesn't have that in-built function .

Comment: @King_Fisher: If `left` is not less than `right` includes the case where both are equal.